# SQL Server 2012 - Optimizing SQL query with functions in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Does anyone have any suggestions on making the following select statement more efficient? It is a very simple query but the SSRS using the code hits the timeout set.

```
SELECT   
   G.A
   ,B = IsNull(Avg(CAST(T.B as decimal)), 0)
   ,C = Sum(T.C)
   ,D = IsNull(Avg(CAST(T.D as decimal)), 0)
FROM 
   TableA as G 
INNER JOIN 
   TableB as T ON T.An_ID = G.An_ID
group by G.A
```

This is a snippet of the code with identical grouping in the bigger script of the SP that the SSRS is using.

Comment: Do you have indexes on An_ID in both TableA and TableB?  Also should there be a GROUP BY clause in there somewhere?

Comment: Yes both have IDs have indexes.

Comment: Are they covering indexes?

Comment: Did you try running it in SQL Server Management Studio with the show query plan option? Did it recommend any indexes?

Comment: what is the type of `T.B` and `T.D` ? perhaps, maybe, probably you could use CAST(Avg(T.B as decimal)) instead of `Avg(CAST(T.B as decimal))`, doing the cast `inside` aggregated function makes the query a little slower

Comment: Show the execution plan.

Comment: This query is syntactically incorrect, because it is an aggregation query with no `group by`, and `g.a` is not in an aggregation function.

Comment: T.B and T.D are both float.

Comment: I can't post the execution plan but it basically says that there is a problem with the cluster index that are in the two tables in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT G.A, B = IsNull(Avg(CAST(T.B as decimal)), 0),
       C = Sum(T.C), D = IsNull(Avg(CAST(T.D as decimal)), 0)
FROM TableA G INNER JOIN 
     TableB T
     ON T.An_ID = G.An_ID
GROUP BY G.A;
```

You want indexes on `TableB(An_ID)` and `TableA(An_Id, A)`.

My guess is that the joins are producing a very large number of intermediate rows.  You can get the count by doing:

```
select sum(a.cnt * b.cnt)
from (select an_id, count(*) as cnt from tablea group by an_id) a join
     (select an_id, count(*) as cnt from tableb group by an_id) b
     on a.an_id = b.an_id;
```

You can find the offensive combinations:

```
select top 100 a.cnt * b.cnt, a.an_id
from (select an_id, count(*) as cnt from tablea group by an_id) a join
     (select an_id, count(*) as cnt from tableb group by an_id) b
     on a.an_id = b.an_id
order by a.cnt * b.cnt desc
```